# If the universe is a closed spacetime structure, can we assign a center of mass to it?

Tags: cosmology, space, mass

If we envision the universe like a balloon but in 3D, is it possible, in general, to assign a of global center of mass?

Comment: No, just like the closed 2D surface of a balloon doesn't have any center, so doesn't the 3D volume of a closed Universe.

Comment: @pela Doesn't it depend on the mass distribution? If there are two masses on opposite sides of the balloon, there will be a ring  of CoM. For a one-sided distribution, it will lay on one side. For just one mass, it will be somewhere in that mass.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. That would violate the cosmological principle, though.